# MarkLogic - email address in URI

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a document where email address is the unique key and ideal for identifying the document. Can I have email address in the URI? Do I have to encode the email address.

We typically suffix with .json.

```
/customer/1234.json
```

Could I suffix uri with .com? Any best practices while using email address in uri?

```
/customer/abc@gmail.com
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend encoding the email address before concatenating it to your uri string. fn:encode-for-uri would work, but a different encoding might work better in combination with a web interface.

HTH!